# accessing operator overload functions using object pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, operator-overloading

I am implementing this class from https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/operator-overloading

```
class Matrix {
public:
  Matrix(unsigned rows, unsigned cols);
  double& operator() (unsigned row, unsigned col);        // Subscript operators often come in pairs
  double  operator() (unsigned row, unsigned col) const;  // Subscript operators often come in pairs
  // ...
 ~Matrix();                              // Destructor
  Matrix(const Matrix& m);               // Copy constructor
  Matrix& operator= (const Matrix& m);   // Assignment operator
  // ...
private:
  unsigned rows_, cols_;
  double* data_;
};
inline
Matrix::Matrix(unsigned rows, unsigned cols)
  : rows_ (rows)
  , cols_ (cols)
//, data_ ← initialized below after the if...throw statement
{
  if (rows == 0 || cols == 0)
    throw BadIndex("Matrix constructor has 0 size");
  data_ = new double[rows * cols];
}
inline
Matrix::~Matrix()
{
  delete[] data_;
}
inline
double& Matrix::operator() (unsigned row, unsigned col)
{
  if (row >= rows_ || col >= cols_)
    throw BadIndex("Matrix subscript out of bounds");
  return data_[cols_*row + col];
}
inline
double Matrix::operator() (unsigned row, unsigned col) const
{
  if (row >= rows_ || col >= cols_)
    throw BadIndex("const Matrix subscript out of bounds");
  return data_[cols_*row + col];
}
```

In my main program I am declaring

```
Matrix *m = new Matrix(20,20)
```

Now how to access the elements ?
Normally

```
Matrix m(20,20)
```

will do the job.
But how to access in the other case ?
I tried

```
*m(i,j) - didn't work
m->operator()(i,j) - didn't work
```

Comment: `m->operator()(i,j)` should work.

Comment: simply drop the `new` and create the matrix via `Matrix m{20,20}`. Even if you do dynamically allocate the matrix you never have to work with a raw pointer (use smart pointers then)

Comment: `new Matrix()` makes no sense. It's line doing `int* i = new int(1);` instead of `int i = 1;`.

Comment: 康桓瑋 Thank you. I don't know why, but previously it did not work. Now it's working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(*m)(i,j)` should do the trick. But then you might as well implement an equivalent `at` method so you can write `m->at(i,j)`.